Using signature with child does not work when using POO PHP
PHP Version: 8.2.17
It works:
class Request {}

class FormRequest extends Request {}

function test(Request $request) {
    print_r('buuu!' . get_class($request));
}

test(new FormRequest());

Result:
buuu!FormRequest


It does not work:
class Request {}

class FormRequest extends Request {}

class Animal {
    public function test(Request $request) {}
}

class Giraffe extends Animal {
    public function test(FormRequest $request) {
        print_r('buuu!' . get_class($request));
    }
}

(new Giraffe())->test(new FormRequest());

Result:
Fatal error: Declaration of Giraffe::test(FormRequest $request) must be compatible with Animal::test(Request $request) in /home/user/scripts/code.php on line 14


Now the question arises: WHAT IS THE DIFFERENCE BEYOND POO?

What is this POO?

The two test() methods you define must have the same arguments. In your code they haven't, one is test(Request $request) and the other is test(FormRequest $request). Make the argument types the same and it will work: https://3v4l.org/PtfKZY

@KIKOSoftware, I understood it, but, why?

PHP has no method overloading, it only has overriding.
The overload is linked to object orientation, and PHP does not support this model like Java and C# do.
Using loose functions, procedurally and functionally speaking, there is no overloading, there is only a reception of parameters that have a hereditary chain for the same "parent" element, that is, they are of the same type genetically speaking.
With OOP, this doesn't happen, you are obliged to have the same signature (even if they are of the same type) and even if a "specialization (FormRequest)" doesn't break the contract, the same number of parameters and the order between them must be maintained.
I saw some people commenting on breaking the Liskov principle (SOLID), but I can't see it as a breach of contract, as I'm creating a child object that has everything the parent has, that is, if the FATHER calls method Y, the child will have it and the application will continue to work, anyway...
